# KX refinery connection and get data from tables

Tags: connection, kdb, refinery

I need to connect to Kx refinery and get the table data .
Table Name : stock

```
I tried to use:
\c `:host:port //gives output as 25 80i
getTicks[`stock;startDate;endDate] //does not work ,shows error near getTicks
```

Comment: The command `\c` is used to set the console size, not for connections. Typically you would use `hopen` instead but I am not familiar with KX refinery. The docs also say `getTicks` takes a dictionary as its argument.

Answer (score 2):

There's several issues in your example that I think could be solved by reading the IPC docs: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/ipc/.

First and foremost `\c` is used for setting a limit on the size of the virtual console display. The `25 80` you see is just the size of the console (height and width)

So assuming this is a standard q process you're trying to connect to (e.g rdb, hdb, gateway) then you should just be able to open the port via:

```
q)h:hopen`:host:port
```

Note that this assumes there's no username or password required, in which case it would be

```
q)h:hopen`:host:port:username:password
```

Then, if getTicks is a function defined on the remote process you can run something like:

```
q)res:h(`getTicks;`stock;startDate;endDate)
```

to perform a synchronous (blocking) request to the server to call your function with your required arguments.

Comment: there is a rank error near h.  @SeanHehir

Comment: Probably an issue with getTicks in that case. Thomas' comment on your initial post mentions that getTicks should take a dictionary, so maybe that's the problem?

Comment: `getTicks` takes a single dictionary as a paramter: https://code.kx.com/refinery/server-api-guide/getticks.html  
 ``q)res:h(`getTicks;params)``